# How to pass custom headers like ama-client-ref on flight offers search, flight offers price and Flight create orders while using Node SDK

Tags: node.js, nestjs, amadeus

I wanted to pass custom headers while making requests on Amadeus APIs. I don't find any code examples in the official documentation provided by the Amadeus. So, anyone who has the solution for it. Please do share your solutions here.

I wanted the problem to be addressed and the official documention to mention things like this.

Comment: To have a custom header in your request with SDK, I'm afraid that you would need to modify the SDK code 'request.js'. which can cause issues during updates or maintenance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.